# If a patent has been issued, can it still be invalidated by prior art?

Tags: prior-art, law

Assuming the invention disclosed in a patent issued by the USPTO has been described in a book two years before it was submitted, can this patent still be invalidated by this prior art? If yes what is the procedure to follow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  An issued patent is **presumed** to be valid, but a challenger can produce prior art to demonstrate that the claims of the patent were anticipated or rendered obvious.

There are administrative post-grant procedures for challenging an issued patent, and, of course, anyone who is sued by a patent holder can support a defense of invalidity by producing prior art - even possibly art that was originally considered by the Patent Office when the patent was issued.

Comment: There is some information related to the *post-grant review* process here: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/528/what-is-the-time-period-allowed-to-get-a-post-grant-review

Comment: I have also posted a comment that discusses mechanisms for challenging patent rights here: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/590/over-time-which-patent-legislation-applies-current-or-past

Answer (score 5):

> That said, **[the America Invents Act](http://judiciary.house.gov/issues/issues_patentreformact2011.html)** does create a new avenue for
>   challenging patents, albeit a limited one. It allows third parties to
>   introduce evidence of so-called “prior art” (proof the invention had
>   already been invented) to block patents from being issued, and it also
>   **introduces a new framework to challenge patents in a “post-grant review” process.**

Source: http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2011/09/obama-signs-patent-reform-bill-crustless-sandwich-still-patented

Comment: There is a good description of the various post-grant proceedings, like PGR, IPR, CBM etc. here http://fishpostgrant.com/inter-partes-review/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a video of Tim Meyer explaining post-grant proceedings as of 2009. This is before the "new framework to challenge patents in a "post-grant review" process" so keep that in mind when watching it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUjsCv8khdQ